# SQL Server agent job [Event] to be uploaded on hosting server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-hosting, sql-agent-job

I have a question: I am uploading my website to a free hosting site somee.com for testing purposes. I have uploaded all the asp.net source files and `.mdf` and `.ldf` files successfully.

For my website I have written a SQL Server job that executes after every five minutes.

I just want to know how to upload or run this SQL Server job steps on the hosting server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you need to ask the somee.com support whether or not they support SQL Server, and in particular, SQL Server agent jobs. If they don't support that, then you're out of luck ... *free* providers most often use SQL Server  **Express** if they even support SQL Server - and the free Express edition does **not** support SQL Server Agent jobs, unfortunately.

Comment: ok.. so do u know any of the free hosting sites that supports sql server aent jobs.?? and how to upload these sql agent jobs on hosting server.?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to talk to the hosting provider.  They probably will not support doing this, especially if they are a free hosting provider.